# I can't find all the errors occurring in my codes

Tags: matlab

For matalb there's an error at line 9, where I define dy(1), but it doesn't say what kind of error.

```
function dy=pred_prey(t,y)
k=1;
a=2/3;
d=4/3;
f=@(x)cos(x.^2)
r=@(t)integral(f,0,t);
mu=@(t)13/20-(3/5)*exp(-(3/t));
dy(1)=(y(1)+k)*r-a*y(1)*y(2);
dy(2)=-mu*y(2)+d*y(1)*y(2);
dy=dy';
```

Comment: MATLAB *always* tells you what error. Please provide the full error message.

Comment: Not enough input arguments.

Error in pred_prey (line 9)
dy(1)=y(1)*r-a*y(1)*y(2);
 
pred_prey is the name of the file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You define `r` as an [anonymous function](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/anonymous-functions.html), but you don't pass any arguments to it when you call it on line 9. The line should be (I assume):

```
dy(1) = (y(1)+k)*r(t)-a*y(1)*y(2);
```

Incidentally, you're going to have the same problem on the next line where you call `mu` with no arguments as well.